# Add default filter to categories in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, category, price, filter

I would like to show products in all categories only if their tier prices were set. I had some success with a plugin for the Layer Model (with afterGetProductCollection). I just added join to the select (joined the ...tier_price table).

One problem remains: the product count and pagination is wrong (as if the filters weren't applied) and no matter what I try, I am not able to find a way to apply a central filter condition.

Comment: Could you share your plugin code, I am trying to modify my collection removing some products from the collection and collection size or pagination is breaking, in the catalog list view for example it shows 2 products instead of 24. See my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287528/magento-2-custom-product-collection-size-problem-after-removing-products-from-co for more info

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody ever comes across such problems, where you filter the collection and the count is off... There was a problem in at least up to 2.1.9. When you use a GROUP BY in your statement, it doesn't work as expected. The solution can be found in a (resolved) Magento issue:

In Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php getTotalNum() function must be:

```
public function getTotalNum() {
return count($this->getCollection()->getAllIds());
}
```

and in your Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection override class the getLastPageNumber() function should be:

```
public function getLastPageNumber()
{
$collectionSize = count($this->getAllIds());
if (0 === $collectionSize) {
return 1;
} elseif ($this->_pageSize) {
return ceil($collectionSize / $this->_pageSize);
} else {
return 1;
}
}
```

Also see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4767

Comment: That you shouldn't edit core files but use a Rewrite or the like, is implied ;-)